# Bash script not copying files

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script which is pretty simple (or so I thought - but I don't write them very often):

```
cp -f /mnt/storage/vhosts/domain1.COM/private/auditbaseline.php /mnt/storage/vhosts/domain1.COM/httpdocs/modules/mod_monitor/tmpl/audit.php
cp -f /mnt/storage/vhosts/domain1.COM/private/auditbaseline.php /mnt/storage/vhosts/domain2.org/httpdocs/modules/mod_monitor/tmpl/audit.php
```

The script copies the contents of auditbaseline to both domain 1 and domain 2.

For some reason it won't work.  When I have the first line in on its own  it's okay but when I add the second line I can't get it to work it locks up the scripts and they can't be accessed.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Check your script with `cat -A file` or `cat -v file` for special characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you perhaps create this script on a Windows machine? You should make sure that there are no CRLF line breaks in the file. Try using `dos2unix` (http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/dos2unix1.html) to convert the file in that case.

Comment: I'll have a go at converting _ I haven't done it before so might take me a while